# update from python2.7 to python3

Tags: python-3.6

I have python2.7.12 right now and I want to switch it to python3.

Tried sudo **apt-get install python3.6** and it gives me this:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package python3.6
>   E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.6'
>   E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.6'

and tried **sudo apt-get install python3** and it gives me this:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   python3 is already the newest version (3.5.1-3).
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: This means that Python 3 is already installed and you can start using it!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your distribution and version (and ultimately the distro's package maintainers). Do `sudo apt-get update` to get the newest package information, then retry your commands. If 3.6 is still not available, you will either have to resign to using 3.5, wait for the maintainers to package 3.6, or compile it yourself from source.

In my personal opinion, there's very small difference between 3.5 and 3.6 (and 3.7), basically no difference at all when compared to the jump between 2.7 and 3.5. Given that Python 2 is officially dead, and the many improvements available in Python 3, you should absolutely start using at least 3.5 that you already have available, and not worry about 3.6 unless you specifically have a package or application that requires it.

Comment: @h4z3: True, but I don't think most packages converted to f-strings yet. And even without f-strings, 3.5 is a huge improvement on 2.7. If you really really need something from 3.6, compile from source.

Comment: I don't deny OP should switch to 3.x. :) I just mentioned something that for some people is a huge deal between those versions. And to be wary of such differences. - E.g. SO answers/examples use f-strings a lot, so one needs to know this little fact before writing questions with "the answer for question x doesn't work, please help" (I've already seen such things - person didn't specify version and was angry that provided answers didn't help...)